# Boostrap Form validation form checkbox is not reset

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I'm working on bootstrap form validation. Here `resetForm();` is working fine but the checkbox is unable to reset on form submit. i have tried like this `$('.form-check-input').val();` and `$('.form-check-input').val(' ');`, `$('.form-check-input').reset();` but not getting. can anyone suggest me how can I reset the checkbox on form submit.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // reCaptcha random numbers generate
  function randomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  };

  function generateCaptcha() {
    $('#captchaOperation').html([randomNumber(1, 5), '+', randomNumber(1, 10), '='].join(' '));
  };

  generateCaptcha();

  // Form validations
  $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({

      fields: {
        first_name: {
          validators: {
            stringLength: {
              min: 2,
            },
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your first name'
            }
          }
        },
        last_name: {
          validators: {
            stringLength: {
              min: 2,
            },
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your last name'
            }
          }
        },
        email: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your email address'
            },
            emailAddress: {
              message: 'Please supply a valid email address'
            }
          }
        },

        city: {
          validators: {
            stringLength: {
              min: 4,
            },
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your city'
            }
          }
        },
        state: {
          validators: {
            stringLength: {
              min: 4,
            },
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please select your state'
            }
          }
        },
        zip: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please supply your zip code'
            },
            regexp: {
              regexp: /^\d{10}$/,
              message: 'The US zipcode must contain 5 digits'
            }
          }
        },
        agree: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'You must agree with the terms and conditions'
            }
          }
        },
        captcha: {
          validators: {
            callback: {
              message: 'Wrong answer',
              callback: function(value, validator, $field) {
                // Determine the numbers which are generated in captchaOperation
                var items = $('#captchaOperation').html().split(' '),
                  sum = parseInt(items[0]) + parseInt(items[2]);
                return value == sum;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },

      // Success Message display
      submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {
        generateCaptcha();
        $('#success_message').css('opacity', '1').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
        //$('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator('resetForm', true);

        var bv = form.data('bootstrapValidator');

        // Use Ajax to submit form data
        $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(result) {

        }, 'json');
        $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator('resetForm', true);
        $('.form-check-input').reset();
      }
    })
    .on('error.form.bv', function(e) {
      generateCaptcha();
    });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js"></script>

<form action="contact-form.php" method="POST" class="needs-validation form-horizontal" id="contact_form" novalidate>
  <div class="form-row row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 mb-3 pr-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 mb-3 pr-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
        <div class="inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 mb-3 pr-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">E-Mail</label>
        <div class="inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 mb-3 pr-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">City</label>
        <div class="inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="city" placeholder="City" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 mb-3 pr-5 ">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">state</label>
        <div class="inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="state" placeholder="State" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 mb-3 pr-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Zip Code</label>
        <div class="inputGroupContainer">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="zip" placeholder="Zip Code" class="form-control" pattern="^[0-9]+$" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-check form-group">
    <input name="agree" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">Agree to terms and conditions</label></a>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">You must agree before submitting.</div>
    <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row row align-items-center">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-6 col-12 control-label" id="captchaOperation"></label>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Success message -->
  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.</div>

  <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send Request</button> -->

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label"></label>
      <button type="submit" class="btn submit">Send Request</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the input element's checked property with jQuery via the `prop` method, setting it to false should do the trick. This would look like `$('.form-check-input').prop(checked, false);`

Comment: it's working fine there is a spelling mistake in your answer correct it. `$('.form-check-input').prop('checked', false);`